# Browser Said Invalid Request When I Tried to Access a Picture of Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Recently, I wrote an app to synchronize photos in my Instagram to another platform. The `GET /v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` result should contains the links to my pictures, like
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/sh0.08/11330602_751572388302808_972254350_n.jpg,
and it went very well. But today after clicking the link, it told me `Invalid Request`. I'm not sure what happened to this cdn link. Any hints would be appreciated.